# Automated insertion from Hive to Elasticsearch

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive, elasticsearch-hadoop

I currently try to find a way to automatically add data from Hadoop text files into elasticsearch. 
We are running HIVE v0.11, Hadoop v2.0.5, Elasticsearch 1.7.1 and elasticsearch-hadoop v2.1.0
The files are stored in different subfolders below the path /tmp/test-log/apache2log named year/month/day
This table creation works in acquire the data from Hadoop:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apache2log(
userIP STRING,
identity STRING,
user STRING,
time STRING,
request STRING,
status STRING,
thread STRING,
link STRING,
callerInformation STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED by '|'
LOCATION '/tmp/test-log/apache2log';
```

But when I try to create a table, that inserts this data in elasticsearch, the creation works fine, but the table is empty. I tried the following command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apache2log(
userIP STRING,
identity STRING,
user STRING,
time STRING,
request STRING,
status STRING,
thread STRING,
link STRING,
callerInformation STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED by '|'
STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
LOCATION '/tmp/test-log/apache2log'
TBLPROPERTIES(
'es.nodes'='1.2.3.4', 
'es.resource'='sam3/apache2',
'es.net.proxy.http.use.system.props'='false');
```

Variables that are changed from the Defaultsetting:

```
SET hive.input.dir.recursive=true;
SET hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories = true;
SET hive.supports.subdirectories=true;
SET mapred.input.dir.recursive = true;
SET hive.input.format=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveInputFormat;

ADD JAR /usr/lib/gphd/hive-0.11.0_gphd_2_1_1_0/lib/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.jar;
```

I know, there would be the possibility to create a second table for elasticsearch and adding the data using INSERT. But I need the process to be automated, so data added to the files should be inserted into table the time it arrives in the hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no way to this. If it were, there would be no need of defining storage handlers of tables in seperate external tables.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10333652)

Comment: @ebramtharwat A negative answer *is* an answer.